# Meaning of "bring them away" in Shakespeare's "Measure for Measure" (Act2, scene1)?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs, early-modern-english, shakespeare

In [act II, scene 1](https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/MM_F1/scene/2.1/index.html), of *Measure for Measure*, Elbow says:

> *Elbow*. Come, **bring them away**: if these be good people in a Common-weale, that doe nothing but vse their abuses in common houses, I know no law : **bring them away**.

I did some research on [ShakespearesWords.com](https://www.shakespeareswords.com) and on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bring_off), and found only [bring off](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bring_off). Does it mean to take someone away?

Comment: Elbow seems to speak a load of nonsense on his appearance, making malapropisms and saying other strange things; and the scene is full of paradoxes, puns, and language play. I'm sure if you get a good scholarly edition of the play it will explain in more detail.

Comment: @All If you know the answer, **write an answer** and justify it. Do not comment.

Comment: I could have sworn I left a comment here that addressed only the meaning of **away** and did not address **bring**, so it wasn't an answer.  Sometimes thoughtful comments on  one aspect of a question may turn on a lightbulb for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. It is the usual difference between *take* and *bring*. If he had said “take them away”, it would have been a demand that the people in question be separated from him and removed to another place. But “bring them away” is a demand that they be brought with him as he goes before Angelo – not separated from him.